# Unable to get the type of data user inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except

I am trying to get the type of data user inputs, but I am getting some issues with code. I tried with the below code:

```
def user_input_type():

    try:
        user_input = int(raw_input("Enter set of characters or digit"))
    except:
        try:
            user_input = str(user_input)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        return type(user_input)

    return type(user_input)

print user_input_type()
```

but it gives me 2 warnings before running the code.

1. Local variable `user_input` might be referenced before assignment.
2. Too broad exception clause such as no exception class specified, or specified as `Exception`.

After running the code when I enter digits it gives me proper value  but when I enter character it gives me an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user_input' referenced before assignment

Please help.

Comment: It always helps to know on what line those warnings are appearing. You should _always_ include that information.

Comment: This is because `user_input` will not be assigned in case an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'user_input' outside of the `try-catch`.

**Ex:**

```
def user_input_type():
    user_input = raw_input("Enter set of characters or digit")  #---->Outside try-except
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
    except:
        try:
            user_input = str(user_input)
        except Exception as e:
            print e

    return type(user_input)

print user_input_type()
```

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. Rather, you should do `user_input = raw_input(...)` outside of the try, then do the `int` call inside.

Comment: @Rakesh, the above code is not appropriate as if user enter character then it by default return type(None) which will str. Also, if you try to print the character user input, it will print None if user enter non digit character

Comment: @Pradeep. If a user enters a character it will not be a NoneType